# HTML JSon POST C#

Tags: c#, html, json, post

Tenho a seguinte class:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string content { get; set; }

    public int itilcategories_id { get; set; }

}
```

E a seguinte tarefa:

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateTicketAsync()
{
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>();
tickets.Add(ticket);

var parametro = new
{
     input = tickets.ToArray()
 };

 var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parametro);
 var contentString = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

 contentString.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
 contentString.Headers.Add("Session-Token", session_token);

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("apirest.php/Ticket/", contentString);

            return response.Headers.Location;
 }
```

No content do ticket é passado HTML, mas ele é convertido para JSON para poder ser enviado pelo Post, o que faz com que ele não apareça corretamente no website para o qual é enviado. Alguém sabe como resolver o problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os n que aparecem em cima não deveriam de aparecer e entre aquelas categorias deveria existir parágrafo.

**HTML:** antes de ser convertido

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"\">\r\n<head>  \r\n<meta http-equiv=\"\"Content-Type\"\" content=\"\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"\"><style type=\"\"text/css\"\"> body,p,td {{font-size:9.0pt;line-height:115%; color:#595959 ;line-height:115%;font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';}}</style> \r\n</head><body><p>Foi recebida a seguinte informacao relativa a umasubscricao JASMIN:</p><br>\r\n<b>Utilizador CIS: </b>{1}</p><b>Nome: </b>{0}</p><b>Morada: </b>{2}</p><b>Codigo Postal: </b>{3}</p><b>NIF: </b>{4}</p><b>Email: </b>{5}</p><b>Parceiro: </b>{6}</p><br>\r\n<br><b>Subscricao Ant: </b>{7}</p><b>Contrato CIS Ant: </b>{8}</p><br>\r\n<br><b>Solucao: </b>{9}</p><b>Subscricao: </b>{10}</p><b>Contrato CIS: </b>{11}</p><b>Inicio: </b>{12}</p><b>Fim: </b>{13}</p><b>Pagamento: </b>{14} {15}</p><b>Ref MB: </b>{16}</p><br>\r\n</body></html>",
```

Qualquer dúvida avisem!

Comment: e qual a string depois de ser convertido ?

Comment: `string x = "seu html";  x = x.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","<br>");` ?

Comment: parágrafo no json ?, a formatação vc faz na página, no html...

Comment: sim, o json nao precisa ter paragrafo, o json tem dados. Onde você for exibir esses dados, você formata como quiser...

Comment: sim, é irrelevante ter quebras de linha no json, a formatação deve ser feita quando for exibida pro usuário

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda